# Как проверить, существует ли строка MySQL в PHP?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте! Проверяю, есть ли строка в базе данных. Почему-то корректно работает только для 
$login = user; $pass = user; Для bin, bin, а также других строк возвращает 0. Скриншот базы по ссылке ниже.

```
$login = $_POST["login"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login = '$login' && pass = '$pass'") or die ("Error.<hr>" . mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    print "success=1";
} else {
    print "success=0";
}
```

http://clck.ru/8tmdv

Comment: сделай var_dump($_POST) перед отправкой данных в бд, может приходит что-то не то из формы,

попробуй заменть && на AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенном вами коде ошибок нет. Убедитесь, что делаете выборку из правильной таблицы и из правильной БД, и что в сохраненных значениях нет пробелов и кириллицы, например.

PS: Не храните пароли в открытом виде.

Comment: Забыл, что поменял базу. С утра посмотрел свежим взглядом, сразу ошибку нашел. Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

обработай переменные прежде чем их затолкнуть в запрос:

```
$login = $_POST["login"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

$login = trim($login);
$pass = trim($pass);
```

Попробуй сделать запрос такого вида:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '".$login."' AND pass = '".$pass."'") or die ("Error.<hr>" . mysql_error());
```

А вместо того что бы засунуть все в IF сразу сделай переменную примерно так:

```
$cols = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($cols > 0) {
        print "success=1";
    } else {
        print "success=0";
    }
```

Comment: и в чем разница? вы человеку предложили фильтровать данные, это можно сделать и потом, у него запрос не отрабатывает.

а на счет mysql_num_rows($result); тут итак все нормально - если возвращается 0,null,false - то это false если больше, то это true. Там по-хорошему вообще вместо всего этого if можно было написать:  

print 'success=' . (int)mysql_num_rows;

Comment: Вы советуете почти полную ерунду. Экранировать данные перед подстановкой в запросы, конечно надо, но вы совершенно не понимаете, что вы предлагаете в своем коде и зачем. Во-первых, почитайте зачем нужен htmlspecialchars, во-вторых, дополнительная локальная переменная никакких плюсов не дает, скорее, наборот.